# jQuery changing img src of html image doesn't refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to achieve that hitting A or D to change the image, from 1.jpg to 2.jpg and back. The following code changes the width, but not the images, I have made sure the images are in the same directory as the js file.

```
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
        var checkWebkitandIE_D=(e.which==100 ? 1 : 0);
        var checkMoz_D=(e.which==100 ? 1 : 0);

        if (checkWebkitandIE_D || checkMoz_D){
            $("#pic").attr("scr", "1.jpg");  // NOT working
            $("#pic").attr("width","300"); 
        }

        var checkWebkitandIE_A=(e.which==97 ? 1 : 0);
        var checkMoz_A=(e.which==97 ? 1 : 0);

        if (checkWebkitandIE_A || checkMoz_A){
            $("#pic").attr("scr", "2.jpg");  // NOT working
            $("#pic").attr("width","200"); 
        }

    })
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `scr` != `src` fix typo ...

Comment: @ArunPJohny, Perfect as ever!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5hba528u/2/

Answer (score -1):

html

```
<img src="" id="pic" alt="" />
```

jquery

```
   $(document).keypress(function(e){
      var checkWebkitandIE_D=(e.which==100 ? 1 : 0);
      var checkMoz_D=(e.which==100 ? 1 : 0);

      if (checkWebkitandIE_D || checkMoz_D){
          $("#pic").attr("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64,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");  // NOT working
          $("#pic").attr("width","300"); 
      }

      var checkWebkitandIE_A=(e.which==97 ? 1 : 0);
      var checkMoz_A=(e.which==97 ? 1 : 0);

      if (checkWebkitandIE_A || checkMoz_A){
          $("#pic").attr("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64,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");  // NOT working
          $("#pic").attr("width","200"); 
      }

  })
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://codepen.io/Arif_Iqbal/pen/epRZzJ)